# How to use positioning-related jQuery within a specific jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, positioning, conflict, jquery-masonry

I am using a jQuery plugin for certain content in a specific tab. The jQuery is http://masonry.desandro.com/ and the tabs are http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/. When I try to load Masonry inside one of the tabs, it simply does not work, or displays incorrectly (everything stacks on each-other in top left). I'm unsure how to combat this problem, and so far have tried only running masonry after the tab has been clicked, after the tab content becomes visible, and other things of that nature.

Please point me in the right direction! thanks.

Comment: If you're saying that you *can* get it to work if you run the masonry *after* the tab has been clicked then this will undoubtedly be down to JavaScript not knowing the dimensions of an unrendered element. Basically, if your tab is `display:none` then most browsers wont bother to calculate any dimensional info for it (or it's children).. this will leave Masonry to calculate the element as having width & height of 0.. which could quite easily lead to having all your masonry elements floating top left. Try hacking easytabs to use `visibility:hidden` & `position:absolute` instead of `display:none`

Comment: Great suggestion! I'll get back to here with results.

Comment: Wow! that was easy. I spent 4 hours trying to mess around this... Anyways, the fix I did was just load the easytabs code after the masonry code and place both within the imagesLoaded function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be related to the fact that I am using images with the masonry and easy tabs. To fix this, you must use Masonry's imagesLoaded recomendation, and set up the code as so:

```
var $container = $('#masonry-container-name');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.item-class-or-id'
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#easytabs-container-name').easytabs();
    });
});
```